# Where should i place the scriptmanager

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to rebuilding the code of one asp.net project to another asp.net project.

but i am stuck some where ...

I drag and dropped the master page and the views (4 nos) into the master page.

now i need to drop scriptmanager.. where should i need to drag and drop this?

- inside the multiview
- outside the multiview
- inside view? if so which view ? view 1 ? view 2? view 3? view 4?

What actually the script manager do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would put the ScriptManager at the top of the Master page outside of any Multi-View. The ScriptManager is a what is used by the Microsoft controls to provide AJAX functionality.

Answer (score 6):

Thomas answer is correct, I'd like to add, to be more specific that placing the ScriptManager right below the Master's page Form tag is the best place:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
```